# (vec) vs [ ] vector literal

Tags: recursion, vector, clojure, literals

I've got two functions here that I though would return the same thing but they don't.  I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Any ideas?

```
user=> (defn foo [x] (when (> x 0) (conj (vec (foo (dec x))) x)))
#'user/foo
user=> (defn bar [x] (when (> x 0) (conj [(bar (dec x))] x)))
#'user/bar
user=> (foo 5)
[1 2 3 4 5]
user=> (bar 5)
[[[[[nil 1] 2] 3] 4] 5]
```

Comment: Compare `[(range 0 5)]` to `(vec (range 0 5))` and the difference should become clear.

Comment: (...or see that comparison done for you at https://ideone.com/n17O8Q)

Comment: Also note the difference between `vec` and `vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[xs]` creates a one-element vector, containing the single item `xs`. In contrast, `(vec xs)` does not create a one-element vector containing the item `xs`. Instead, it creates an n-element vector, containing each item in `xs` separately. A function which does the former is `vector`: `(vector x y z)` is conceptually the same as `[x y z]`. Compare to `(list x)` and `(seq x)`: the former creates a one-element sequence containing its input, while the latter converts its input to a sequence.

Of course, if you are going to `conj` onto the result of `vector` you might as well just build the 2-element vector directly: instead of `(conj (vector x) y)`, write `[x y]`.